# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

If I call this function on my dataset:

```
def reconstruct_flight(data, sequence_lenght, flight_len, param_len):
    
    stack_factor = int(flight_len/sequence_lenght)
    
    data_reconstructed = []
    for i in range(0, len(data_clean), stack_factor):
        if i<len(data_clean):
            data_reconstructed.append(
                data[i:i+stack_factor].reshape(
                    [flight_len, param_len])
                )
        
    return np.array(data_reconstructed)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (1500,77)
```

But if I run the `for` loop in the console without passing it as a function:

```
data_reconstructed = []
    for i in range(0, len(data_clean), stack_factor):
        if i<len(data_clean):
            data_reconstructed.append(
                data[i:i+stack_factor].reshape(
                    [flight_len, param_len])
                )
```

It works as expected. Why is that ?

Comment: where is `data_clean` defined?

Comment: If `data` is already a numpy array, you should reshape in numpy (maybe cropping first) instead of creating lists and then casting as an array

Comment: @Learningisamess 'data_clean' is a numpy array of shape (300, 50, 77) and the reshape is (10, 1500, 77). Could you detail how I can stack this element together without using a list but using a reshape only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reshaping, if you are keeping the same data contiguity and just reshaping the box, you can reshape your data with

```py
data_reconstructed = data_clean.reshape((10,1500,77))
```

if you are changing the contiguity from one axis to another, you will need to add a permutation of the axes beforehand https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html

Comment: Is the order of the data maintained using this method ?
In my case I need to stack together every 30 elements of data_clean because they belong to the same category.

Comment: This data is the output of an autoencoder, I broke down the full sequence (1500) into 30 smaller sequence (50) to avoid having too much info to store in the model. But to compare the results I need to reconstruct the original sequence by respecting the order.

Comment: That's what I was trying to get to. By looking at you example, and assuming your `data_clean` array is C order (instead of Fortran order) you are not changing the contiguity, so you only need a reshape.